# Kotlin execution time almost 20 times higher depending on invocation order

Tags: java, performance, kotlin, garbage-collection, jvm

I was measuring the performance of inline functions when I encountered this really weird behavior.

```
fun normalFunction(block: () -> Unit) = block()

inline fun inlineFunction(block: () -> Unit) = block()
```

The following piece of code produces the output `0.315988524`.

```
var x = 0

println(measureNanoTime {
    repeat(1_000_000_000) {
        normalFunction {
            x += it
        }
    }
} / 1E9)
```

Replacing `normalFunction` by `inlineFunction` produces the output `0.307185642`; slightly faster as one might expect.

Now to the weird part. If I run both pieces of code directly in the same function (renaming `x` to `y` in one instance or encapsulating both blocks with `run { ... }`) then the produced output varies drastically depending on which block is run first:

- `normalFunction` then `inlineFunction` produces the output `0.320697598` and `0.310288507`
- `inineFunction` then `normalFunction` produces the output `0.310213495` and `5.515626813`

The weirdness ends when the two pieces of code are extracted to individual functions. The only thing that comes to my mind is GC but the inline function shouldn't really have any overhead memory wise. Does someone have an idea why this might happen? Should I file a bug report?

Here are the two complete versions for clarity:

```
fun main() {
    run {
        var x = 0

        println(measureNanoTime {
            repeat(1_000_000_000) {
                normalFunction {
                    x += it
                }
            }
        } / 1E9)
    }

    run {
        var x = 0

        println(measureNanoTime {
            repeat(1_000_000_000) {
                inlineFunction {
                    x += it
                }
            }
        } / 1E9)
    }
}
```

```
fun main() {
    run {
        var x = 0

        println(measureNanoTime {
            repeat(1_000_000_000) {
                inlineFunction {
                    x += it
                }
            }
        } / 1E9)
    }

    run {
        var x = 0

        println(measureNanoTime {
            repeat(1_000_000_000) {
                normalFunction {
                    x += it
                }
            }
        } / 1E9)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is 100% normal for any JVM code.  The JVM optimizes code as it runs more, so of course later code will run faster than earlier code.

Comment: I'm not sure if you got my question right. Performance varies depending on executing order of two slightly different and independent pieces of code and only as long as they are placed directly in the same function.

Comment: It does not happen on my machine with Java 14. They both take around 0.32-0.35, no matter the order. And I think @LouisWasserman could be right. It is hard to measure the performance of Java code, because quite a lot of things happen under the hood. It is discouraged to write such simple tests as yours as results may be misleading. You should use JMH or similar tool to see if you will reproduce your results.